# Docker-compose: Mounting a tmpfs usable by non-root user

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm creating docker images that will later be used on a Kubernetes with tight settings:

1. read-only file system
2. non-root USER

For test purposes I can emulate 1) with a `read_only: true` in the docker-compose config. I then have to add some directories for places with write activity, such as /run and /var. But if I try to use a tmpfs as shown [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#tmpfs) the directory is owned by root:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 40 Nov 27 11:05 /var
```

Is there a secret option to make it `drwxrwxrwx`? Is there an alternative (besides plain disk directories)?

Running:

- Docker version 18.06.0-ce
- docker-compose version 1.8.0
- Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can specify a tmpfs mode:

```
docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name tmptest \
  --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/app,tmpfs-mode=1770 \
  nginx:latest
```

https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/#specify-tmpfs-options

---

With the older 2.x compose file syntax, you can specify it like:

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  my_app:
    image: my_app
    read_only: true
    restart: always
    tmpfs:
      - /run:mode=770,size=1k,uid=200,gid=10000
```

https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/698#issuecomment-429688027

---

For the 3.x syntax, with the long format volume definition, you'll want to follow this issue:

https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1285

Comment: The `mode` parm seems ignored, but the `uid` one works so I can get the thing going. The strange thing is that the flags aren't the same on the two tmpfs I create: `drwxr-xr-x` for `/var/httpd` and `drwxrwx---` for  `/run/httpd`.

Comment: @xenoid my personal solution to problems like this is usually to start an entrypoint as root inside the container, fix any file permissions and uid's, and then do an `exec gosu` to drop from root to a user. The container is then effectively running as the user, but not every security team accepts that option.

Comment: I have such a security team unfortunately :) But since I can set the UID I won't need to fix the access rights.

Comment: Plot twist: `mode=` works this morning, after I removed a `RUN chown ...` in the Dockerfile...

Comment: As of 2022, tmpfs-mode "Defaults to 1777 or world-writable" and yet I'm getting EACCESS errors, so I think the problem is likely more complicated than this.

Comment: Could it be a bug? I am running into a similar issue, the mountpoint is 755 even with `mode` set explicitly

Comment: I notice the same issues, there has to be a bug. Or I do something stupid. Maybe  tmpfs in octal. So should we set it to `1777`? https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/#specify-tmpfs-options

Answer (score 7):

This works for the current master-branch spec:

```yaml
services:
  my_app:
    image: my_app
    volumes:
      - type: tmpfs
        target: /app/tmp
        tmpfs:
          mode: 01777
```

The leading `0` is significant, do not remove.

Ensure the directory does **not** exist beforehand, otherwise it would ignore the permissions. The place to do it is in your `Dockerfile`:

```bash
RUN rm -rf /app/tmp
```

Do not bother with `uid` or `gid`: as of 2023-05 they are **not** implemented. Link to the current source: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/api/types/mount/mount.go#L103-L135 ([permalink](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/2adec6c8c0c6aea2fe7af0d5ab001876ff28c41a/api/types/mount/mount.go#L103-L135))

Comment: Excellent! You saved the day! A shame that it is so poorly implemented and undocumented :(

Comment: 2024 and this is still an issue. This solution worked for me. I wonder why you have to remove the tmpfs manually in the Dockerfile?

Comment: @sleepystar96 "Ensure the directory does **not** exist beforehand, otherwise it would ignore the permissions." That is, if you own the Dockerfile and are able to mkdir/chmod from there, cool, more power to you.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. I did try to chmod in the Dockerfile directly but it did not work. However, following your instructions exactly (adding 01777 in docker-compose file, and adding `RUN rm -rf /app/tmp
` to Dockerfile) worked.

Comment: Wow, this is absurd. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I could configure a tmpfs mount with a non-root user with no issues, but then when the container restarted I'd get permissions errors for the file being created by the running application within the container inside that directory. This solution resolved that problem.